# Yup confirm password validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, formik, yup

I am using Yup https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup and I read https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-password to validate my formik forms.

I do not find a way to have two fields that should be equal to be valid:

- newPassword
- confirmNewPassword

Is there a way to test that both are equal ?

Comment: Do you know how to perform string comparison in JavaScript? You can simply do this yourself without needing `yup`.

Comment: `str1 === str2`, but I want to know if it's possible using Yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine yup.string().oneOf() and yup.ref() methods to achieve the same.

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import YupPassword from "yup-password";
YupPassword(yup);

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  password: yup.string().password().required(),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match"),
});

schema
  .validate({ password: "12345678aB1!", confirmPassword: "12345678aB1!" })
  .then(() => console.log("Valid"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: everything is fine. When I gives same password and confirmpassword after I just add one more char in password field confirmpassword doesn't show any errors but here password & confirmpassword are not same.